How to fix white background problem?
Recently new raspberry pi 4 background is white for reason. It was fine before, but after taking off the case and looking at the pi 4, and reassembling it, after booting it up, the background turned white. Please help.

you either did not reassemble it correctly, or you destroyed a component by electrostatic discharge

Not enough detail. I assume background of a screen? What screen? How is it connected to the Pi? Post detail and photos.


Abandoned post by Unregistered user.

